# How to restrict the input for the html textbox with regex expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm a new learner of javascript. 
So I have this html textbox.

```
<form method="get" id="form" action="number.php">
    <p><input type="text" id="number" name="number" value="0,0" size="4"/></p>
</form>
```

And with javascript (not jquery), a regex expression and without changing the html code, I only want to allow an input of positive numbers or a pos. number followed by a comma followed by only one number after comma.

E.g. 5 or 23 or 141 or 0

E.g. 15,9 or 0,0 or 356,4 or 77,7

This is how my javascript function looks like but I am not sure how to call the function for the input of this textfield "number". And not sure if my regex is correct.

```
number.onkeypress = function validate(s) {
    var rgx = /^\d+(,\d{1,1})?$/  ;
    if(rgx.test(s)) { 
       return true; 
    }
    else { 
       return false; 
    } 
}
```

So my 2 questions are:

1. How can I check with a regex-function the input for the textbox, so only numbers and one comma is allowed?
2. Is my regex expression correct?

Comment: Have you tested against test inputs on http://www.regexpal.com/ or the like?  Your `test` approach is good.

Comment: Thx. I haven't, but now once you mentioned, I did. The expression looks correct, though the problem is, my html test site doesn't accept any kind of inputs. I can't type in the textbox at all, so something must be wrong. I thought the problem is either the regex expression or how I call the function.

Answer (score 1):

You try this

```
<p><input type="text" id="number" name="number" value="0,0" onblur="javascript:validate()" size="4"/></p>

<script>

function validate() {
    var numberVar = document.getElementById("number"); 
    var rgx = /^\d+(,\d{1,1})?$/;
    if(!rgx.test(numberVar.value)) { 
       numberVar.value = "";
       numberVar.focus();
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Did you see my answer?

Comment: Yeah, I ve seen your first answer with the regex site. Thanks. And to this answer: I am not allowed to change the html code, you changed the html code. It is for a homework and I can't manipulate the html code.